# sed to convert from multiline to single does not work

Tags: bash, sed, apache-kafka

I am working on a shell script that would read filenames based on a topic name, read the file content, convert the text to a single line and post the message to kafka using kafka consumer.

For converting the contents of the json file, I am trying to use sed and seen many examples and tried them all.  But none of them seem to convert the multiline text to single line so I could use it to post to kafka topic

This is the script I am trying to write

```
declare -A topicconfig
while read -r topic configfile; do
  topicconfig["$topic"]="$configfile"
done <config_params.txt

for topic in "${!topicconfig[@]}"; do
  echo "filename : ${topicconfig[$topic]}"
  textFromFile=$(sed -e 's/[\n|\r]$//g' "${topicconfig[$topic]}")
  echo "textFromFile : $textFromFile"
  /bin/kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server=${BOOTSTRAP_SERVER} \
    --producer.config ~/client.properties --topic ${topic} <<< "${textFromFile}"
  echo "configuration added to  $topic"    
done
```

What would be the reason sed doesn't convert the string to single line?   Or how else could I change the  call to sed  to  achieve the conversion from multiline to a single line?

The  sed version is

[image]

Thank you

**UPDATE**

*Sample  Input*

```
 {
    "eventType": "Dashboard_Configuration",
    "version": 1,
    "environments": [
      "dev",
      "qa",
      "stage",
      "prod"
    ],
    "events": [
      {
        "sourceSystem": "FINTRX",
        "events": [
          {
            "parentEventName": "Benefit",
            "stageCount": 3,
            "stages": [
              {
                "order": 1,
                "stageName": "IngestStage",
                "stageType": "INGEST"
              },
              {
                "order": 2,
                "stageName": "AvroStage",
                "stageType": "AVRO"
              },
              {
                "order": 3,
                "stageName": "ReconciliationStage",
                "stageType": "RECONCILIATION"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

*Expected Output*

```
{ "eventType": "Dashboard_Configuration", "version": 1, "environments": [ "dev", "qa", "stage", "prod" ], "events": [ { "sourceSystem": "FINTRX", "events": [ { "parentEventName": "Policy Financial Transaction", "stageCount": 3, "stages": [ { "order": 1, "stageName": "IngestStage", "stageType": "INGEST" }, { "order": 2, "stageName": "AvroStage", "stageType": "AVRO" }, { "order": 3, "stageName": "ReconciliationStage", "stageType": "RECONCILIATION" } ] } ] } ] }
```

*The  Actual Output*

Same  as input - for the last iteration - some other iteration it was dropping the r and n from the string - but putting it on one line

Thanks

Comment: Added sample input and expected output

Answer (score 3):

sed is designed to work on lines, it wouldn't do a good job working across lines in most cases.

A much easier way to delete newlines is `tr -d '\r\n'`:

```
$ printf "PRE"; printf "%s\n" a b c; printf "POST"; echo
PREa
b
c
POST
$ printf "PRE"; printf "%s\n" a b c | tr -d '\r\n'; printf "POST"; echo
PREabcPOST
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash's built-in string search and replace to delete newline characters

```sh
# Delete any newline character
read -r -d '' textFromFile <"${topicconfig[$topic]}"
textFromFile="${textFromFile//[$'\n\r']/}"
```

Now if you want to replace newlines with a space using the same feature

```sh
shopt -s extglob # Needed for extended glob patterns

read -r -d '' textFromFile <"${topicconfig[$topic]}"

# Replace one or more newlines by a single space
textFromFile="${textFromFile//+([$'\n\r'])/ }"
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  Is it  possible to combine  the two lines ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace: (`sed`)

```
textFromFile=$(sed -e 's/[\n|\r]$//g' "${topicconfig[$topic]}")
```

With: (`awk`)

```
textFromFile=$(awk '{printf $0}' "${topicconfig[$topic]}")
```

With: (root's `tr` solution)

```
textFromFile=$(tr -d '\r\n' < "${topicconfig[$topic]}")
```

**NOTE**: Neither of these ideas deal with the management of 'extra' white space, eg, removing leading spaces/tabs in a line and replacing with a single space (as shown in OP's expected output)